# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. Whats wrong?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, initialization

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.**

How to fix this error? Occurs when trying to `update-database.`

I checked the connection string, everything is correct there. I'm trying to connect to SQL Server.

[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqdRB.png)

[appsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz3tA.png)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - 
see the answer in the link on why images can hinder others helping you.